# Inequality with 4 absolute values

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am exploring the topic of absolute value inequalities and I am really wondering how to solve this inequality without graphing:

$$ |x|+2|x+1|-3|x+2|+4|x+3|≤7 $$

I know it is possible to solve it by considering all 16 cases for this equation, but that seems very unappealing to me. Do you guys see any smart solutions?

Comment: I don’t see 16 cases, I see 5 cases. $(i) x < -3, (ii) -3\le x < -2, (iii) -2\le x < -1, (iv) -1\le x <0$ and $(v) x \ge 0$. Is that still too many? I can’t think of a “smarter” solution.

Comment: For starters, all sixteen cases aren't required. When $x>0$ then so are the others. That saves a lot. Similarly, when $x+4<0$ so are the others.

Comment: May be inequality$|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ can work here

Comment: @TheStudent I solved some examples with this method, but I cannot see its' application here...

Comment: @User8128 You are right. I was thinking about considering the positive and negative values for every single absolute value. What you said saves lots of time. I am still pondering though, do you maybe see any smart or alternative solutions? I am really curious on this topic.

Comment: @Hi_I_like_math_a_lot it’s hard for me to imagine what a smarter solution would look like. You could try to add unnecessary levels of sophistication and abstraction I’d you want, but simpler is almost always better, and it seems difficult (maybe impossible) to completely avoid breaking it down into cases at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the answer, we can reduce the cases to 4 only, we can see from inequality that, x has to be less than 0, it cannot be more than or equal to it, you can verify yourself by putting in x=0!

After a minute or two of calculation, we come to know that x cannot be less than -4, so our domain to check has reduced to: -4 < x < 0.

Within this, we can check for 4 cases:

CASE I: -1 <= x < 0
Solving in this you will get:
x E [-1,-0.5]          EQ1....

CASE II: -2 <= x < -1
Solving this:
x E [-1.5,1)           EQ2....

CASE III: -3 <= x < -2
Solving this:
x E [-3,-2.25]         EQ3....

CASE IV: -4 < x < -3
Solving this:
x E [-3.75,-3)         EQ4....

By the union of all 4 equations, we get:
x E [-3.75,-2.25] U [-1.5,-0.5]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's some good reasoning. It was very helpful.